# How to reference included data sets in R.app

Tags: r, macos

I'm trying to do some analysis on the data sets that are included in the R.app on OSX command line. How do I reference columns? I usually use $ in other programs but I get an error here saying it is invalid for atomic vectors. Is there another operator I should be using?

Comment: What dataset are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

Not all built-in datasets are of class `data.frame`. `Titanic` is one such dataset. As its help file (`? Titanic`) describes it is:

> A 4-dimensional array resulting from cross-tabulating 2201 observations on 4 variables.

You can see this by using `str`:

```
> str(Titanic)
 table [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Class   : chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
  ..$ Sex     : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..$ Age     : chr [1:2] "Child" "Adult"
  ..$ Survived: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
```

Thus, you cannot use `$` extraction. Instead, use `[` indexing, such as:

```
> Titanic[,'Male',,]
, , Survived = No

      Age
Class  Child Adult
  1st      0   118
  2nd      0   154
  3rd     35   387
  Crew     0   670

, , Survived = Yes

      Age
Class  Child Adult
  1st      5    57
  2nd     11    14
  3rd     13    75
  Crew     0   192

> Titanic[1,,,'Yes']
        Age
Sex      Child Adult
  Male       5    57
  Female     1   140
```